# Two different POST requests being made to the same route at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am creating a voting app and I have an issue that I don't know how to work around. I think I have just structured my app badly. I have a POST route like so

```
app.route('/poll-create')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            var userID; //variable to store the authentication id for the user
            var incoming_id = Object.keys(req.body)[0];

            console.log(incoming_id);

            serverHandler.newPoll(req, res, db, function(id) {
                user_id = id;
            });

            res.redirect('/new-poll');


        });
```

I am passing in some form data to this route like so from the HTML

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='new-poll-form'>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type='text' name='title' class='form-control' placeholder='Title' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label>Options</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control poll-options" rows="5" placeholder='Options' name='options'></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary submit-butt'>Submit</button>
                   </form>
```

The data entered in the form is directly sent to the route with no need for an AJAX request on my part. I assume this is because I am setting the method='post' in the form.

Now, my problem is that I also need to pass in an object from the JavaScript file linked to the above HTML file. I am doing that through an AJAX call like so

```
$('.submit-butt').on('click', function() {
                        console.log('From in here');
                        ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('POST', appUrl + '/poll-create', response.authResponse.userID, function(data) {

                        }));
                    });
```

Here is the AJAX function below

```
'use strict';
var appUrl = window.location.origin;

var ajaxFunctions = {
  ready: function ready (fn) {
      if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
         return;
      }

      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
         return fn();
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
  },
  ajaxRequest: function ajaxRequest (method, url, data, callback) {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      console.log('Inside ajaxRequest');
      console.log(data);

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.response);
         }
      };

      xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xmlhttp.send(data);
  }
};
```

So, the first issue I face is that when I try console.log the data sent through the AJAX request (assuming I send in an object), the output I get is {'object Object': ' '}. Which is why I opted to send in only the userID from that object. In that case I get this, {'userID': ' '}. Its annoying but I can work with it at the very least.

My second issue is that, even if I work my way around the first issue, I am essentially making two AJAX calls to the same route. So, I don't have access to the form data and the userID at the same time. So, I can't insert them into a single document. How do I work my way around this? Is there a better way of passing around data than I am doing currently? Please help! 
I am using body-parser to parse incoming data and formidable to parse incoming form-data.

Comment: For first issue, use console.log(JSON.stringify(object)) to convert object to readable JSON.

Comment: where do you get response.authResponse.userId from? does that depend on the first call?

Comment: @vlatkokaplan - that doesn't work. When I try that, it returns {"object Object":" "}, which is the JSON representation of the exact same issue I was dealing with earlier.

Comment: @mimarcel - So, response.authResponse is an object I get back from the Facebook JavaScript SDK. No, it doesn't depend on the other call. It is independent of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make only one request like this:

```
$('.submit-butt').on('click', function() {
    var formData = {}; // Prepare form data.

    // Add code to get form data as json and insert it in formData
    // You can either use Javascript for this or, with jQuery you can look into https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/.

    formData.userId = response.authResponse.userID; // This is how you add new data.

    // Make ajax request with formData.

    return false; // It is important to return false so the normal form POST request will not trigger, since you already did all that job with Ajax.
});
```

Comment: This sounds like it will work except for my second issue, which is that everytime I pass an object through an AJAX request, and I try to console.log that in the route, I get it in the form {'object Object': '  '} and the same thing will happen when I implement your solution. How do I work around that?

Comment: And another question, since I am submitting form data manually by collecting it through jquery, will it still be sent as multipart data? Because if it is, will the req.body data be accessible through using body-parser? Since body parsers documentation mentions that it cannot handle multipart data?

Comment: Alright, I tried your method and it works so far. I just need to change a lot of tiny little functions to make it work like it was working earlier. Hopefully shouldn't be too bad. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be spamming comments on your answer but I don't understand why this worked only when I JSON.stringified my data before passing it into the ajax call. Does that have to be the case when you are setting the request header as application/json?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun to be honest, I don't know why it would work only when the data is stringified. But if it works, then that's very good! :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is probably to just send everything at once (except the ID which you don't know obviously). You may be able to do that with a form, or with AJAX.  You could use something like jquery to collect the form data or even just a simple function to pull the data out of the form before sending it as JSON.

Comment: Right, so thats my problem. I would have to make a second AJAX call for the ID right? That would defeat the whole purpose of sending everything on my own. I would still need to make a second AJAX call for the ID, and I would not get that at the same time as the form data.

Comment: If you need the id on the client then you need either something like AJAX or a page refresh.  I just thought perhaps you could do your second step on the server after the record was created.

Comment: Not sure that will work because my Facebook SDK is a client side function, and thats what returns the object to my server. So, I don't know how I'd gain access to that directly from the server side.